# SharePoint : Convert claim formats

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, claims, claim-provider

Is there any Microsoft utility or tool available in context to SharePoint which can migrate user from one identity provider to another with user information format change, i.e. migrating user from one SharePoint farm to another SharePoint farm with different identity provider and claim provider?

This is very common user case when a company acquire another company and want to migrate the users in the main SharePoint farm from an acquisition farm. In short I am looking for an automated utility/tool to achieve this.

Example:
I need to convert the Windows Authentication permissions and userID formats over to the format used by our Identity Provider.

```
Sample Of Current Name Format: i:0#.w|corp\user1
New Name Format Needed: i:05.t|adfs20|test.user1@testorg.com
```

Comment: interesting question, made me wonder if when assigning permissions to a claim, the claim "identity" considers only the value or the provider is taken in account too. Probably the second one.

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly complex, so I'm just providing links to the how-to to perform the Windows Auth to SAML auth migration. It would be best to review the below links and then ask any specific questions you may have on the process.

How to:

[Migration of Windows claims authentication to SAML-based claims authentication in SharePoint Server 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/dn744263.aspx)

Potential issue:

[The Convert-SPWebApplication command cannot convert from Windows claims to SAML in SharePoint Server 2013](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3042604)